# How to write Angular 2 code inside Angular1.x code based project?

Tags: angularjs, angular

My current project was implemented in Angular1.x and now I have requirement to add new features to exiting code base.

Can I add Angular 2 code into my Angular1.x code base porject?.

Please share what are the steps I need to follow.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

While this is sort of going the opposite way, in first bootstrapping the app as Angular 2+ and then bootstrapping AngularJS 1.x on top of it, it may be of assistance.

https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b

The goal in using this method would be to migrate your code to the latest versions little by little, while not entirely breaking your existing code.

If you're starting a new project, or if your project is rather small, I'd strongly suggest just working in the latest version by itself.

However, being the maintainer of a rather large and complex AngularJS 1.x app, I can certainly see the value in something like this.

Comment: no problem. best of luck in your migration! I decided to stick with AngularJS for an existing project due to time constraints. I'd love to see it updated to Angular though... someday.